# Return type of Task.Run vs. Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: vb.net, delegates, async-await

I've been reading and re-reading Stephen Cleary's article [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and Stephen Toub's article [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).  I'm trying to make sense of this.

Given the following code:

```
Dim s = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(New Func(Of Task(Of String))(
    Async Function()
        Await Task.Delay(10000)
        Return "Hello"
    End Function))

Dim t = Await Task.Run(New Func(Of Task(Of String))(
    Async Function()
        Await Task.Delay(10000)
        Return "Hello"
    End Function))
```

Why is it that `s` is of type `Task(Of String)` and `t` is of type `String` (which I would expect)?

I can also do the following:

```
Dim u = Await New Func(Of Task(Of String))(
    Async Function()
        Await Task.Delay(10000)
        Return "Hello"
    End Function).Invoke()
```

where `u` is a `String`, and I can add the function:

```
Async Function GetValueAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(10000)
    Return "Hello"
End Function
```

and then use it like this:

```
Dim v = Await GetValueAsync()
```

and `v` is also a `String`.

So why isn't `s` a string?

In Stephen Cleary's article (linked above), he says:

> [Task.Factory.StartNew] Does not understand async delegates...The problem
>   is that when you pass an async delegate to StartNew, it’s natural to
>   assume that the returned task represents that delegate. However, since
>   StartNew does not understand async delegates, what that task actually
>   represents is just the beginning of that delegate.

I feel like this is the key to the whole thing, but I don't understand "what that task actually represents is just the beginning of that delegate."  What does "the beginning of that delegate" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `Await` as "unwrapping" a `Task(Of T)` to the resulting type `T`.

> Why is it that s is of type Task(Of String) and t is of type String (which I would expect)?

The type of `Task.Factory.StartNew(New Func(Of Task(Of String))(...)` is `Task(Of Task(Of String))`, so the `Await` unwraps it to `Task(Of String)`.

The type of `Task.Run(New Func(Of Task(Of String))(...)` is `Task(Of String)`, so the `Await` unwraps it to `String`.

> What does "the beginning of that delegate" mean?

As I describe in my [Async Intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), every asynchronous method begins executing synchronously, and only becomes asynchronous at the first `Await`. So, if you are using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, it returns a `Task(Of Task(Of T))`. The "outer" task represents the synchronous execution of the delegate, up until the first time `Await` decides to yield to its caller. At that point, the `Await` will *return* a `Task(Of T)` to its caller. This returned task is the "inner" task of `Task(Of Task(Of T))`, and it represents the *completion* of that asynchronous delegate.

But the only thing you really need to know is to just use `Task.Run` and not `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Okay, so when S. Taub says in his article "When you pass an `Action` to `Task.Run`: `Task.Run(someAction)`; that’s **exactly equivalent** to: `Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);`" (emphasis added) it's only, as he says, "equivalent" because the action does not return anything, so what we really get from that call is a `Task(Of String)` which then gets "unwrapped" into a `String` due to the `Await`?

Comment: @roryap: None of your original code is using `Action`. That statement is correct if you pass an `Action` delegate. It does not hold if you pass `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>`. Stephen clarifies this later when he states "the implementation of **this** overload of Task.Run is basically equivalent to ..."